# Return from child and exit execution in further parent function, without duplication code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I do have a class to return response.

```
    class responseHandler {

    constructor(payload){
        this.payload = payload;
    }
    
    createUser(){
        this.confirmMethod('post');
        return this.response(201,"I am home");
    }

    response(status,response){
        return {
            "status" : status,
            "response" :{
                "message" : response
            }
        };   
    }
    
    confirmMethod(method){
        if(method!==this.payload.method) return false;
        return true;
    }

};
```

Now i would like to exit from createUser Method if `this.confirmMethod` return false. which i can do like this

```
createUser(){
        if(!this.confirmMethod('post')) return false;
        return this.response(201,"I am home");
    }
```

But problem with this code is, i have to copy paste this `if` condition in all methods in which i have to confirm method. ideally i would like to exit from parent too, if child return false without checking it specifically like current code, is something like this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

> is something like this possible ?

Most likely, no.

In languages like JS, the only one that is responsible for the execution flow of the function is the function itself.
Unfortunately, this is the main problem of other kind of issues, like `await` propagation when using promises or inability to return from function while using `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `for`.

So as there are no good answers for these issues, there should not be any answers for yours as well.
At least all the answers will have some sort of external constructions, which basically means that we just replace `if` instead of getting rid of it. Which sounds like cheating.

The only possible way I see so far is to use exceptions.
But it is not only might be slow, but will also be the *wrong* way to use exceptions mechanism.
But anyway it is up to You : )